# Bootstrap 5 - Navigation in carousel is not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 and want to implement an image carousel and a modal.

Here is my example code.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/0088ff?text=animals+ratione" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/009999?text=animals+illum" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/007766?text=animals+dignissimos" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/0077aa?text=animals+ad" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/0000aa?text=animals+totam" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/000022?text=animals+et" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/0066ee?text=animals+sed" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/00dd33?text=animals+neque" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>ab natus nemo</h3>
    <p>Architecto corrupti nulla dolorum sint. Rerum consequatur quidem et autem nobis qui. Hic fugiat voluptate dignissimos sed officia in odio.</p>
    <h4>$5.99</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#buyModal">
                    Buy
                </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="buyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="buyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="buyModalLabel">Buy: ab natus nemo</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You are about to purchase for $5.99.</p>
        <form method="POST" action="">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="m46pmcbo0G2yuMVNyfwpcY07AomhmCY5AD2OixFy"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the image carousel the two navigation buttons (next & previous) do not work.

[image]

In my modal window the close button is not rendered properly.

[image]

I tried out the standard examples from bootstrap, but they are not working with my code.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues with the HTML structure, I'll address them:

- The prev/forward buttons should be of type `<button type='button'>` with an `data-bs-target` attribute set to the id of the modal, you are using an `<a>` with `href`, change it to:

  ```
  <button type="button" class="carousel-control-prev" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </button>
  ```
- For the Modal close button, you are setting the content by yourself, that's not needed as that's part of the Bootstrap styling.

  Also, the attrubute should be `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` instead of the `data-dismiss="modal"` you currently have.

  The following is enough:

  ```
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  </button>
  ```

  [image]

---

Working Demo:

<sup>Note: **Please enlarge the demo so you see the carousel controls**</sup>

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/640x480/0088ff/FFF?text=animals+ratione" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/640x480/009999/FFF?text=animals+illum" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/640x480/007766/FFF?text=animals+dignissimos" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/640x480/0077aa/FFF?text=animals+ad" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/640x480/0000aa/FFF?text=animals+totam" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/640x480/000022/FFF?text=animals+et" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/640x480/0066ee/FFF?text=animals+sed" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/640x480/00dd33/FFF?text=animals+neque" class="d-block w-100" alt="ab natus nemo">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="carousel-control-prev" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="carousel-control-next" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>ab natus nemo</h3>
    <p>Architecto corrupti nulla dolorum sint. Rerum consequatur quidem et autem nobis qui. Hic fugiat voluptate dignissimos sed officia in odio.</p>
    <h4>$5.99</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#buyModal">
                    Buy
                </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="buyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="buyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="buyModalLabel">Buy: ab natus nemo</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You are about to purchase for $5.99.</p>
        <form method="POST" action="">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="m46pmcbo0G2yuMVNyfwpcY07AomhmCY5AD2OixFy"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your problem is that you are using bootstrap 5 and using code form  the documentation of [v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/).

check this [v5 doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/https://)

and  same with modal -
check  [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the {position: fixed} css in button all the code is ok i review the code.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="image1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="image2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="image3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev" style="position: fixed;">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next" style="position: fixed;">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your  tags for the next and previous buttons with this. I tried it in VS-Code and works perfectly now. At least the carousal is functional. I think it also had something to do with "data-bs-slide" properties as well. Hope that was helpful.

```
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
```

Comment: In my example the libraries are loaded before the HTML is rendered. It seems that there are some issues with the code.

Comment: @Carol.Kar, I have copied your code and compared it with bootstrap example carousal, and making the changes above in my answer seems to have fixed the issue you were facing with the carousel buttons  not working.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 syntax for carousel controls  uses the data-bs-slide attribute instead of data-slide.
Can check here in the documentation for changes.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).